# Determine if a group contains a value in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I would like return rows of a dataset where groups satisfy two conditions. That is,

1. I want to know if the number of unique values in a group is greater than 1, and
2. I want to know if the group contains a particular value.

I am getting hung up on the latter!

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    dict(
        item=[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        location=[
            "new york",
            "boston",
            "boston",
            "boston",
            "ohio",
            "ohio",
        ],
        store=[
            "store 1",
            "store 1",
            "store 1",
            "store 2",
            "store 1",
            "store 3",
        ],
    )
)
```

| item | location | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | new york | store 1 |
| 0 | boston | store 1 |
| 1 | boston | store 1 |
| 1 | boston | store 2 |
| 0 | ohio | store 1 |
| 0 | ohio | store 3 |

I can check for #1 easily using `filter`, `n_unique()`, and `over` as follows:

```py
df.filter(
    (pl.col("store").n_unique() > 1).over(["item", "location"])
)
```

| item | location | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | boston | store 1 |
| 1 | boston | store 2 |
| 0 | ohio | store 1 |
| 0 | ohio | store 3 |

However, I would like to add to the filter to return rows where the *corresponding group* contains "store 3".

I tried this (and variations of it):

```py
df.filter(
    (pl.col("store").n_unique() > 1).over(["item", "location"])
    & (pl.col("store").is_in(['store 3']))
)
```

| item | location | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ohio | store 3 |

But this is only returning a single row. And actually the result makes some sense to me but I was hoping to return the whole group. For example,

| item | location | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ohio | store 1 |
| 0 | ohio | store 3 |

I'm quite sure I'm missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated. Loving Polars so far without a doubt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(pl.col(...) == value).any().over(group)` can be used to test if a value exists within a group.

You can "and" the multiple conditions and run them through `.over()`

`(one & two).over(group)`

```py
df.filter(
   (
      (pl.col("store").n_unique() > 1) &
      (pl.col('store') == 'store 3').any()
   )
   .over('item', 'location')
)
```

Using `pl.all_horizontal()` is also another option.

```py
df.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(
      pl.col("store").n_unique() > 1,
      (pl.col('store') == 'store 3').any()
   )
   .over('item', 'location')
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬──────────┬─────────┐
│ item ┆ location ┆ store   │
│ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---     │
│ i64  ┆ str      ┆ str     │
╞══════╪══════════╪═════════╡
│ 0    ┆ ohio     ┆ store 1 │
│ 0    ┆ ohio     ┆ store 3 │
└──────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```